# Unable to display 2D chart correctly with Teechart on Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, teechart

Having fun evaluating Teechart for .NET Monotouch for iOS. Run into several problems that cannot solve. Basically I am trying to present a 2D bar chart with two or three series with up to 24 data points.

Here is my test code

```
    chart3.Aspect.View3D = false;
    chart3.Legend.Visible = false;
    chart3.Chart.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyle = Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyles.Auto;   

    Axis left=chart3.Axes.Left;
    left.Grid.Visible = false; 
    left.Automatic=false;
    left.Minimum=0;
    left.Maximum=20;
    left.Increment=1;

    Axis bottom=chart3.Axes.Bottom;
    bottom.Visible=true;
    bottom.Grid.Visible = false; 

    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar bar1=new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar();
    chart3.Series.Add(bar1);
    bar1.Add(12.0,"Jun 2012");  
    bar1.Add(8.0,"Jul 2012"); 
    bar1.Add(0.5,"Aug 2012"); 
    bar1.Add(6.7,"Sep 2012"); 
    bar1.Pen.Width = 0;
    bar1.Gradient.Visible = true;
    bar1.GetSeriesMark += (series, e) => {object v=series.YValues[e.ValueIndex];   e.MarkText=""+v;};

    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar bar2=new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar();
    chart3.Series.Add(bar2);
    bar2.Add(8.0,"Jun 2012"); 
    bar2.Add(5.0,"Jul 2012"); 
    bar2.Add(5.0,"Aug 2012"); 
    bar2.Add(14.0,"Sep 2012"); 
    bar2.Pen.Width = 0;
    bar2.Gradient.Visible = true;
    bar2.GetSeriesMark += (series, e) => {object v=series.YValues[e.ValueIndex];   e.MarkText=""+v;};
```

Above code creates two 2D bar style series with four points.

Here is the result I am getting
[image]
The major problem is that all bars are floating 0.5 point above zero (notice 8.5 on the left axis where value is 8). Scrolling up shows this 
[image: another image]
Second issue I am facing is that the library doesn't take into consideration Maximum value set for the last axis.
If I set Aspect.View3D to true that chart looks much better
[image] 
3D comes with its own set of issues but we need 2D anyway.

My question is: what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you're correct. I can reproduce the problem here.
A fix will be included into the next maintenance release which will be available soon.
In meantime, a workaround would be to set to Manual the ZoomScroll style, which makes to use the default zoom and scroll of the TeeChart library :
Code :

```
_controller.chart.Chart.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyle = Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyles.Manual
```